# Why does my java script work perfectly in jsFiddle but not in any browser?

Tags: javascript

please help me! been stuck for very long. I coded the exact same thing in my html file but it is not working at all.

i inserted the javascript under the HEAD section.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/26/)

The HTML:

```
<div id="content">

<div id="colone">

     <div id="introbox" class="test">
     </div>


     <div id="infobox" class="test">
     <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #666;width:160px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;">
    INFO
    </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div id="coltwo">

     <div id="aboutbox" class="test">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #666;width:250px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;">
    ABOUT
    </div>
    </div>


     <div id="gallerybox" class="test">
     <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #666;width:260px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;">
    GALLERY
    </div>

     </div>
</div>    


<div id="colthree">

     <div id="contactbox" class="test">
     <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #666;width:180px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;">
    CONTACT US
    </div>

    </div>


     <div id="extrabox" class="test">
     <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #666;width:160px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;">
    EXTRAS
    </div>

     </div>
</div>
     ​
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").hover(function() {
    $(".test").not($(this)).css({
        "opacity": 0.1
    });
}, function() {
    $(".test").css({
        "opacity": 1
    });
});
});​
```

Comment: Could you post your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/26/ sorry guys!

Comment: did you load the jquery file in your website?

Comment: Did u include jquery in your version? What error are you getting in your version?

Comment: can you show how you used this code in your webpage

Comment: no i didnt. How do i go about that?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").hover(function() {
    $(".test").not($(this)).css({
        "opacity": 0.1
    });
}, function() {
    $(".test").css({
        "opacity": 1
    });
});
});​
</script>

Comment: how do i load or get the jquery file in my website??

Answer (score 2):

Only three posibilities here

The script should be placed in header section of your web page as it is called `onload`

Second is the jQuery library version which on jsfiddle its 1.7.2 so either your jQuery version is old or you are not using the library at all

Third is that you must be missing `<script></script>` tags as jsfiddle don't need it

Answer (score 0):

The most probably cause for the same is that the script needs to be executed after the DOM is ready which is something ensured by jsfiddle.

It would be great if you provide a link to the fiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/26 heres the link to fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not included JQuery in your header. Add the following:

```
<script src="jquery_js_goes_here"></script>
```

I'd grab the latest and look at using the available cdn (or google's cdn) E.g

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: theres a syntax error after i inserted 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"</script> in the HEAD section.

Comment: @user1657807 There was a typo in ramsinb answer. I fixed it.